# How to connect redis-cli on Windows to redis on Linux (on VMware)

Tags: linux, nosql, redis, vmware

I have Windows 8 as a host and Linux guest on VMware and installed redis on Linux, redis works correctly.

I don't know how to connect a `redis-cli -h [ipAddress]` to redis on Linux with VMware.

1. How to config network on Linux, Windows 8 and VMware ?
2. I don't know which `[ipAddress]` to use to connect redis on Linux with VMware?

[update]

> I have ping from windows  and I can connect redis-cli on Linux (on
>   VMware) to redis-server on Windows.

I use [Install Redis](http://codingsteps.com/install-redis-2-6-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Are you trying to connect to redis remotely from another linux machine?

Comment: no, I use VMware and I don't know configure network for it.

Comment: If this is a networking question, you should ask at http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: Depends on the kind of networking you are using for your linux guest. If bridged, you should be able to grab the ip address of the linux host by running `ifconfig` on the linux command line. Then connect to that.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation with Redis running on Ubuntu 12 on VirtualBox and then running Windows 7 as the host.  I was having trouble connecting from Windows 7 to the Ubuntu machine.

I had to edit my redis.conf (/etc/redis/redis.conf on Ubuntu) file and comment out this line:

```
#bind 127.0.0.1
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a networking/firewall issue. You should connect to the redis server through redis-cli the same way no matter what operating system the server and client are on. This should always be `redis-cli -h [ipAddress]`.